# How to use Sow and Reap instead of AppendTo for faster computations?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

**In this example I used appendTo.**

`f[x_] := x + 1;`
`data = {};`
`For[x = 1, x <= 10, x++,`
`f[x];`
`spec = AppendTo[data, {x, f[x]}]] // Timing // First`

`Out[37]= 0.000054`

`ListPlot[spec]`

[image]

Comment: Does this help you? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181597/understanding-sow-and-reap-documentation/181603#181603

Comment: It doesn't help in my code

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Reap[For[x = 1, x <= 10, x++, f[x];
Sow[{x, f[x]}]
]][[2, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*0.0000701*)
```

but it seems to be slower than your vewrsion.
Use `Table` for a significant faster version:

```
Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 1, 10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.0000199, Null}*)
```

Comment: Rule #1 about learning Mathematica: forget about `For`. It just doesn't exist.