Efficiently collecting results from nested loops
My question involves what is often considered to be horrible Mathematica code; that is, code which is essentially procedural involving nested loops, rather than mapping, threading, and so forth. Here, I'm not interested in how one could avoid the loops and frame a more Mathematica-al solution, but rather about one specific aspect of efficiency.
The following procedure involves nested loops where the information of interest is produced at the innermost level where processLoopVariables operates.
horrible[v_] := Module[
   {i1, i2, i3, i4, n, collection = Range[v^4]},
   
   processLoopVariables[v1_, v2_, v3_, v4_, n_] := 
    collection[[n]] = {v1, v2, v3, v4};
   
   n = 0;
   For[i1 = 1, i1 <= v, i1++,
    For[i2 = 1, i2 <= v, i2++,
     For[i3 = 1, i3 <= v, i3++,
      For[i4 = 1, i4 <= v, i4++,
       n++;
       processLoopVariables[i1, i2, i3, i4, n]
       ](*end innermost loop *)
      ] (*end i3 loop *)
     ] (*end i2 loop *)
    ];(*end i1 loop *)
   collection
   ]; (* end horrible *)

horrible[2]
{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 
  1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 
  1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 
  2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}}

In this example, I collected, into the collection list, the results of the processing. Importantly, the space for the collection is pre-allocated with collection = Range[v^4] so that the processing results are merely assigned to positions in the list. An alternative would have been to use an initially empty list and then use AppendTo as a way of adding the results of each cycle through the processing loop.
Both methods have unpleasant (horrible !) costs. Pre-allocation requires knowing how many results will be produced, which is obvious a priori in this example, but not usually so. AppendTo avoids the pre-allocation cost but comes at the expense of a 10-fold increase in time (at least for this example on my machine).
Are there any better methods of gathering inner-loop processing information? I know nothing of Mathematica internals, but it seems that many in-built functions face similar problems, and which, perhaps, use cleverly coded functions themselves written in Mathematica rather than in the underlying C.

Try Sow and Reap and see how those compare. And do not forget to include all the time spent agonizing over how to make this as fast as absolutely possible and time spent asking for help and waiting for answers and time spent trying to incorporate suggestions into your before and after calculations of how long all this REALLY took to complete.

That is exactly what Sow/Reap were invented for.  To collect data in a loop. Also, better not use For in Mathematica. You can Do instead. There is no need to use For ever in Mathematica. I think it was mistake to even have it in the language in first place. But too late now to remove it.

Me, I’m a fan of For loops. But I agree, Reap/Sow are the tools for the task at hand.

For those who come to this page (my question) unfamiliar with Reap and Sow, as I was, I recommend starting your discovery with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181603 .  And, of course, searching for the SE-Mathematica tag [sow-reap]

@DanielLichtblau  I see how I could substitute Sow[{i1, i2, i3, i4, n}], for where I currently have processLoopVariables[i1, i2, i3, i4, n] , and how I would  then Reap around the outermost For . But I am slightly confused by your use of but in  "I am a fan of For loops but ..." Are you suggesting that Reap-Sow could potentially do away with the For loops, or have I correctly understood how to approach this.

I was only meaning that whereas some people deplore use of For loops, I'm rather fond of them. Using Reap/Sow is sort of orthogonal to what loop type one might use.

As requested by the OP
Using Reap and Sow can allow you to collect results generated by code and is pretty much independent of any process that you use to generate those results.
This can let you avoid some problems with building very large lists and then
later eliminating many unwanted entries. It can also avoid some problems with appending many many times to large lists.
There should be excellent prior answers describing Reap and Sow that can be found with searching.
